# Cometd subscribe works in IE only after webserver restart

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, cometd

I have an interesting cometd issue that only occurs in Internet Explorer (version 9) but not other browsers - chrome/opera/firefox/safari work correctly as expected so I do not suspect that there is anything wrong with the spring/cometd/bayeux configuration.

EDIT: It looks like IE is sending multiple handshake requests on page load whilst the other browsers only send the one, on weserver restart only the one handshake request is sent.

In IE, the init, handshake, and connect are functioning fine but subscribe requests are not receiving broadcasts, however, if the webserver is restarted whilst the IE page is left waiting then ALL subsequent broadcasts are received as expected. If the IE page is refreshed then it reverts to not receiving broadcasts.

I initially thought this might have been a IE connections issue so explicitly set max connections per server to 10 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304129(VS.85).aspx) however this hasn't resolve it.

Script:

```
...

function startSubscriptionStats() {
    cometd.subscribe('/msgs', function (msg) {
        ...
    });
}

function startSubscriptionMsgs() {
    cometd.subscribe('/msgs', function (msg) {
        ...
    });
}

$(function () {
try {
    cometd.registerTransport('long-polling', new org.cometd.LongPollingTransport());
    cometd.registerTransport('callback-polling', new org.cometd.CallbackPollingTransport());
    cometd.getExtension('reload').configure({cookieMaxAge: 15});

    // Configure the cometd bayeux url using the current path with the '/ui' replaced with '/cometd'
    var cometdUrl = document.location.href.match(/^(.*)\/ui\//)[1] + '/cometd';
    cometd.init({
        url: cometdUrl,
        logLevel: 'error',
        appendMessageTypeToURL: false
    });

    // register handshake with callback function that starts the subscriptions
    cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', function (handshake) {
        if (handshake.successful === true) {
            cometd.batch(function () {
                startSubscriptionStats();
                startSubscriptionMsgs();
            });
        }
    });

    // regiser connection callback function that displays modal on disconnect
    cometd.addListener('/meta/connect', function (connect) {
        if (connect.successful === false) {
            probCounter++;
            if (probCounter > 5) {
                showModal("Warning", "Connection to server has been lost - data displayed might be out of date");
                probCounter = 0;
            }
        } else {
            probCounter = 0;
            if (hideModal()) {
                requestData("boardData", initiliseBoard);
            }
        }
    });

    // kick off handshake that should trigger the listener callback above
    debugMsg("Sending handshake request to " + cometdUrl);
    cometd.handshake();
} catch (e) {
    alert("Failed to start up comet: " + e.message);
}
```

Handshake callback starts subcriptions:

```
cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', function (handshakeReply) {
    debugMsg("Handshake responded " + handshakeReply.successful);
    if (handshakeReply.successful === true) {
        cometd.batch(function () {
            startSubscriptionStats();
            startSubscriptionMsgs();
        });
    }
});
```

This is relevant server log output if it helps:

```
2014-10-03 09:08:02,402 CommandController INFO Index requested
2014-10-03 09:08:02,405 CometConfigurer INFO Configuring service nzgui
2014-10-03 09:08:03,562 AbstractLifeCycle DEBUG starting nz.eftpos.internode.gui.support.JacksonBayeuxServerImpl@1a71ec39
2014-10-03 09:08:03,562 443673657 DEBUG Allowed Transports: [callback-polling, long-polling]
2014-10-03 09:08:03,563 AbstractLifeCycle DEBUG STARTED nz.eftpos.internode.gui.support.JacksonBayeuxServerImpl@1a71ec39
2014-10-03 09:08:03,632 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=2, minimumVersion=0.9, supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling, callback-polling], advice={timeout=60000, interval=0}, channel=/meta/handshake, version=1.0} null
2014-10-03 09:08:03,632 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=2, minimumVersion=0.9, supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling, callback-polling], advice={timeout=60000, interval=0}, channel=/meta/handshake, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,642 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=1, minimumVersion=0.9, supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling, callback-polling], advice={timeout=60000, interval=0}, channel=/meta/handshake, version=1.0} null
2014-10-03 09:08:03,642 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=1, minimumVersion=0.9, supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling, callback-polling], advice={timeout=60000, interval=0}, channel=/meta/handshake, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,683 443673657 DEBUG << {id=2, minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true, channel=/meta/handshake, clientId=3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,683 443673657 DEBUG << {id=1, minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true, channel=/meta/handshake, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,684 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=2, minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true, channel=/meta/handshake, clientId=3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,684 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=1, minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true, channel=/meta/handshake, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,733 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=3, subscription=/stats, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi} 3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:03,733 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=3, subscription=/stats, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,735 443673657 DEBUG No authorizers, CREATE for channel /stats granted
2014-10-03 09:08:03,735 443673657 DEBUG Added channel /stats
2014-10-03 09:08:03,735 443673657 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /stats granted
2014-10-03 09:08:03,736 443673657 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /stats granted
2014-10-03 09:08:03,736 443673657 DEBUG << {id=3, subscription=/stats, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,736 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=3, subscription=/stats, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,736 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=4, subscription=/msgs, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi} 3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:03,736 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=4, subscription=/msgs, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,737 443673657 DEBUG No authorizers, CREATE for channel /msgs granted
2014-10-03 09:08:03,737 443673657 DEBUG Added channel /msgs
2014-10-03 09:08:03,737 443673657 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /msgs granted
2014-10-03 09:08:03,737 443673657 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /msgs granted
2014-10-03 09:08:03,737 443673657 DEBUG << {id=4, subscription=/msgs, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,737 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=4, subscription=/msgs, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,740 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=5, connectionType=long-polling, advice={timeout=0}, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt} 4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:03,740 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=5, connectionType=long-polling, advice={timeout=0}, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,741 443673657 DEBUG << {id=5, successful=true, advice={interval=0, reconnect=retry, timeout=30000}, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:08:03,741 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=5, successful=true, advice={interval=0, reconnect=retry, timeout=30000}, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:08:04,439 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=1, data={contents=[nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@18e5d214, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@18432bd1, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@61f1b2c8, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@43109ab4, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@771cc1d1, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@f8bd6f], type=statusUpdate}, channel=/stats}
2014-10-03 09:08:04,830 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=6, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt} 4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:04,830 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=6, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt}
2014-10-03 09:08:04,831 443673657 DEBUG << {id=6, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:08:05,573 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=2, data={contents=[nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@8f738f8, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@1ebd2661, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@1422ba0b, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@73e43280, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@aafacf1, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@138307b2], type=statusUpdate}, channel=/stats}
2014-10-03 09:08:08,423 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=3, data={contents=[], type=board}, channel=/msgs}
2014-10-03 09:08:10,954 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=4, data={contents=[nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@197bd7b3, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@118e35d7, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@f70bf42, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@331c8df9, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@17acf0a6, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@5aeb2e6e], type=statusUpdate}, channel=/stats}
2014-10-03 09:08:12,431 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=5, data={contents=[nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@49e11d13, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@5a3bf049, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@151c76e7, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@7fc24284, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@2a9d29a3, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@3418a230], type=statusUpdate}, channel=/stats}
2014-10-03 09:08:13,574 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=6, data={contents=[nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@3d401808, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@3ae9d4a2, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@4d86f5e5, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@5779b526, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@7763fea7, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@45e3c32d], type=statusUpdate}, channel=/stats}
2014-10-03 09:08:14,327 ServerSession DEBUG Sweeping session 3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:14,327 443673657 DEBUG Removing session 3oavlsfa2fymkb9u87r3qiawi - last connect 0 ms ago, timed out: true
2014-10-03 09:08:14,328 ServerSession DEBUG Sweeping session 2efvlc43yyn7w1jrb69dv62kmw - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:14,328 443673657 DEBUG Removing session 2efvlc43yyn7w1jrb69dv62kmw - last connect 0 ms ago, timed out: true
2014-10-03 09:08:14,328 ServerSession DEBUG Sweeping session 1nszhseiycs785a9adjif7o1t - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:14,328 443673657 DEBUG Removing session 1nszhseiycs785a9adjif7o1t - last connect 0 ms ago, timed out: true
2014-10-03 09:08:15,542 443673657 DEBUG Removed channel /stats
2014-10-03 09:08:15,543 443673657 DEBUG Removed channel /msgs
2014-10-03 09:08:35,452 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=6, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:08:35,468 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=7, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt} 4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt - last connect 30621 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:08:35,468 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=7, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt}
2014-10-03 09:08:35,468 443673657 DEBUG << {id=7, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:09:06,459 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=7, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:09:06,478 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=8, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt} 4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt - last connect 30991 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:09:06,478 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=8, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt}
2014-10-03 09:09:06,479 443673657 DEBUG << {id=8, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:09:37,475 443673657 DEBUG <  {id=8, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:09:37,490 443673657 DEBUG >  {id=9, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt} 4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt - last connect 30996 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:09:37,491 443673657 DEBUG >> {id=9, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt}
2014-10-03 09:09:37,491 443673657 DEBUG << {id=9, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
```

This is the log after the webserver is restarted where upon the client starts to receive broadcasts:

```
2014-10-03 09:24:37,514 AbstractLifeCycle DEBUG starting nz.eftpos.internode.gui.support.JacksonBayeuxServerImpl@f9c27e4
2014-10-03 09:24:37,514 261892068 DEBUG Allowed Transports: [callback-polling, long-polling]
2014-10-03 09:24:37,515 AbstractLifeCycle DEBUG STARTED nz.eftpos.internode.gui.support.JacksonBayeuxServerImpl@f9c27e4
2014-10-03 09:24:37,578 261892068 DEBUG >  {id=39, connectionType=long-polling, advice={timeout=0}, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt} null
2014-10-03 09:24:37,578 261892068 DEBUG >> {id=39, connectionType=long-polling, advice={timeout=0}, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=4ycca35alnk94ret0g8ksw6rt}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,578 261892068 DEBUG << {id=39, error=402::Unknown client, successful=false, advice={interval=0, reconnect=handshake}, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,578 261892068 DEBUG <  {id=39, error=402::Unknown client, successful=false, advice={interval=0, reconnect=handshake}, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,623 261892068 DEBUG >  {id=40, minimumVersion=0.9, supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling, callback-polling], advice={timeout=60000, interval=0}, channel=/meta/handshake, version=1.0} null
2014-10-03 09:24:37,623 261892068 DEBUG >> {id=40, minimumVersion=0.9, supportedConnectionTypes=[long-polling, callback-polling], advice={timeout=60000, interval=0}, channel=/meta/handshake, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,642 261892068 DEBUG << {id=40, minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true, channel=/meta/handshake, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,643 261892068 DEBUG <  {id=40, minimumVersion=1.0, supportedConnectionTypes=[callback-polling, long-polling], successful=true, channel=/meta/handshake, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d, version=1.0}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,652 261892068 DEBUG >  {id=41, subscription=/stats, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d} 21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:24:37,652 261892068 DEBUG >> {id=41, subscription=/stats, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,654 261892068 DEBUG No authorizers, CREATE for channel /stats granted
2014-10-03 09:24:37,654 261892068 DEBUG Added channel /stats
2014-10-03 09:24:37,654 261892068 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /stats granted
2014-10-03 09:24:37,655 261892068 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /stats granted
2014-10-03 09:24:37,655 261892068 DEBUG << {id=41, subscription=/stats, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,655 261892068 DEBUG <  {id=41, subscription=/stats, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,655 261892068 DEBUG >  {id=42, subscription=/msgs, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d} 21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:24:37,655 261892068 DEBUG >> {id=42, subscription=/msgs, channel=/meta/subscribe, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,655 261892068 DEBUG No authorizers, CREATE for channel /msgs granted
2014-10-03 09:24:37,657 261892068 DEBUG Added channel /msgs
2014-10-03 09:24:37,657 261892068 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /msgs granted
2014-10-03 09:24:37,657 261892068 DEBUG No authorizers, SUBSCRIBE for channel /msgs granted
2014-10-03 09:24:37,657 261892068 DEBUG << {id=42, subscription=/msgs, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,657 261892068 DEBUG <  {id=42, subscription=/msgs, successful=true, channel=/meta/subscribe}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,663 261892068 DEBUG >  {id=43, connectionType=long-polling, advice={timeout=0}, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d} 21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d - last connect 0 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:24:37,663 261892068 DEBUG >> {id=43, connectionType=long-polling, advice={timeout=0}, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,664 261892068 DEBUG << {id=43, successful=true, advice={interval=0, reconnect=retry, timeout=30000}, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,665 261892068 DEBUG <  {id=43, successful=true, advice={interval=0, reconnect=retry, timeout=30000}, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,694 261892068 DEBUG >  {id=44, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d} 21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d - last connect 1 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:24:37,694 261892068 DEBUG >> {id=44, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d}
2014-10-03 09:24:37,694 261892068 DEBUG << {id=44, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:24:43,046 261892068 DEBUG <  {id=1, data={contents=[nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@4f88102d, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@6dde2325, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@12d58a7d, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@1771e34, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@335fe8ac, nz.eftpos.internode.gui.web.model.Status@5da48e8d], type=statusUpdate}, channel=/stats}
2014-10-03 09:24:43,079 261892068 DEBUG <  {id=44, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
2014-10-03 09:24:43,097 261892068 DEBUG >  {id=45, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d} 21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d - last connect 5385 ms ago
2014-10-03 09:24:43,097 261892068 DEBUG >> {id=45, connectionType=long-polling, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=21jjt0xf69cxg3fxiastthza4d}
2014-10-03 09:24:43,097 261892068 DEBUG << {id=45, successful=true, channel=/meta/connect}
```

Comment: I have doubts your server log is complete: it shows a session being swept after 10s, but it does not show the messages that this session generated and that were processed on the server. If a session is being swept, it's because there has been some communication problem with the client, and this should be visible from the full server logs. See the [troubleshooting section](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_troubleshooting) of the [CometD documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/).

Comment: Was trying to avoid a large log hoping this was something minor, I'll add a full debug log

Comment: Just noticed, IE sends two handshake requests whilst the other browsers only send one, after the webserver restart IE only sends the one handshake so that is most likely the cause.

Comment: Can you track down why IE is sending 2 handshakes ?

Comment: That's what I've been trying to understand, it's not the scripting from what I can see, and it's only IE that is doing it. It's like a classic threading issue.Unfortunately IE is a targeted browser.

Comment: Well I have a workaround but it's not pretty.
The handshake() is called only once yet IE sends two requests which bayeux picks up as two different sessions, the handshake listener gets triggered twice and subscribes twice and this is what breaks it, so I have simply stuck a boolean on the subscription method to ignore the first subscribe request (for IE browsers).
It's not pretty but it works and weirdly I can't find any online posts about this occurring.